# MongoDB random slow queries - EC2 IOPS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I have a `mongodb`(version: 2.0.8) installation on an `EC2` instance (7GB RAM) and the data size is still less than `1GB`. I am using provisioned `100 IOPS` disk for increased disk performance.

The problem is, I am getting a number of random SLOW QUERIES like the one below, (from mongo log)

> db.UserInfoShared query: { _id: "999081873179" } ntoreturn:1 idhack:1
>   reslen:108 1919ms

Took almost `2 secs` !

It is just an `_id` lookup on a collection with around `100,000` entries each less than `500 bytes` in size. The instance has only mongo running in it and normally such lookups takes less than `0.01 sec`.

What could the possible cause for this? what should I try to get it resolved? Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: Could there be other operations that you are doing on the same mongod process that are causing overall slowness?  It'd be helpful to see more from your log file if that's possible.  Also, you should try running Dex.  Dex is a open-source tool that looks at your slow queries and recommends indexes (http://mongolab.org/#view=dex).

Comment: Also, you should look at production notes docs for MongoDB at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/.  For example, you should mount your volume using either ext4 or xfs and ensure that you turn off atime.

Comment: there is no question that this query is using an index so Dex is unlikely to help. however, the question about what else your MongoDB instance is doing is relevant. For example, are you doing a lot of writes?  occasional slow queries may be coinciding with dish flushes. You might get better response with (a) more information (b) asking this on MongoDB users google group.

Comment: @angela, yes it is ext4 and the atime is also disabled. Actually I followed a very detailed example  http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/ Thanks.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky, I do have a mongodump running on it daily... but the delay timing does not coincide with it. How can I check if its happening cause of disk flush? Thanks.

Comment: disk flush I'm talking about is fsync of your data files which happens by default every 60 seconds.  If you run mongostat you can see fsync column which will have 1 during seconds when fsync happens - you can see if that correlates to slow query times.

Comment: you said that there are a number of random slow queries. are there other ops that are slow besides this one? this one that you posted is using an index, but perhaps there are others that aren't optimally indexed. are there any other ops showing up in the log file (by default it logs anything over 100ms)?

Answer (score 3):

@angela, @Asya, thanks a lot for helping me out.

As it turned out the main cause of latency was mongodb `GLOBAL LOCK` itself. We had a lock percentage which was averaging at 5% and sometime peaks up to 30-50% and that results in the slow queries.

If you are facing this issue, the first thing you have to do it enable mongodb MMS service (`mms.10gen.com`), which will give you a lot of insights on what exactly is happening in your db server.

In our case the LOCK PERCENTAGE was really high and there were multiple reasons for it. First thing you have to do to figure it out is to read mongodb documentation on concurrency,
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

The reason for lock can be in application level, mongodb or hardware.

1) Our app was doing a lot of `updates` and each update(more than `100 ops/sec`) holds a `global lock` in mongodb. The issue was that when an update happens for an entry which is not in memory, mongo will have to load the data into memory first and then update (in memory) and the whole process happens while inside the `global lock`. If say the whole thing takes 1 sec to complete (`0.75sec` to load the data from disk and `0.25sec` to update in memory), the whole rest of the update calls waits (for the entire `1 sec`) and such updates starts queuing up... and you will notice more and more slows requests in your app server.

The solution for it (while it might sound silly) is to `query` for the same data before you make an `update`. What it effectively does is moving the 'load data to memory' (0.75sec) part out of the `global lock` which greatly reduces your `lock percentage`

2) The other main cause of global lock is mongodb's data `flush` to disk. Basically in every 60sec (or less) mongodb (or the OS) writes the data to disk and a `global lock` is held during this process. (This kinda explains the random slow queries). In your MMS stats, see the graph for `background flush avg`... if its high, that means you have to get faster disks.

In our case, we moved to a new `EBS optimized` instance in `EC2` and also bumped our provisioned `IOPS` from `100` to `500` which almost halved the `background flush avg` and the servers are much happier now.